# reading array struct in C++

Tags: c++

I have a project in which i have to read the data file into a struct array called Honda, that sized for 10 rows of data. I am having trouble reading the text file successfully. here the code i have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Honda {
    int id;
    int year;
    string model;
    string trim;
    string color;
    int engine;

};

const int SIZE = 10;

void openInputFile(ifstream &, string);

int main()
{
    Honda arr[SIZE];

    ifstream inFile;
    string inFileName = "C:\\Users\\Michael\\Documents\\inventory.txt";

    openInputFile(inFile, inFileName);

    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) {
        inFile >> arr[count].id >> arr[count].year >> arr[count].trim >> arr[count].color >> arr[count].engine;
    }

    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}

void openInputFile(ifstream &inFile, string inFileName)
{
    //Open the file
    inFile.open(inFileName);

    //Input validation
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Error to open file." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

text file:  inventory.txt

```
1001 2014 Civic LX Red 4
1002 2014 Accord LX Blue 4
1005 2014 Accord EX Gold 6
1006 2014 Civic EX Black 4
1007 2014 Civic LX White 4
1010 2015 Accord EX White 6
1011 2015 Accord LX Black 4
1013 2015 Civic EX Red 4
1014 2015 Civic LX Beige 4
1015 2015 Accord EX Beige 6
```

Comment: Try to avoid using C-style arrays and instead use a `std::vector` or something like it. Your magical limit of 10 is extremely arbitrary.

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file space separated".  There are already too many similar posts here.

Comment: The shown code forgets to read `arr[count].model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were just missing code to read the file line by line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct Honda {
    int id;
    int year;
    string model;
    string trim;
    string color;
    int engine;

};

const int SIZE = 10;

void openInputFile(ifstream &, string);

int main()
{
    Honda arr[SIZE];

    ifstream inFile;
    string inFileName = "C:\\temp\\1.txt";

    openInputFile(inFile, inFileName);

    int count = 0;
    string line;
    while(inFile.good() && (getline(inFile, line)))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> arr[count].id >> arr[count].year >> arr[count].model >> arr[count].trim >> arr[count].color >> arr[count].engine;

        count++;
    }



    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i].id << " " << arr[i].year << " " << arr[i].model << " " << arr[i].trim << " " << arr[i].color << " " << arr[i].engine << "\n";

    }

    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}

void openInputFile(ifstream &inFile, string inFileName)
{
    //Open the file
    inFile.open(inFileName);

    //Input validation
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Error to open file." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: @rafelgonzalez thx for your help when you ran the code did you get inventory.txt?

Comment: i used the sample data you posted and it displays properly.

Comment: @rafelgonzalez ok when i compile it idk why it displays error to open file not sure why

Comment: @rafelgonzalez i think your code is fine, maybe i am not storing it correctly